# Why is this call to LocalFree() causing an error?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am invoking [`GetNamedSecurityInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as follows:

```
PSID pSID = NULL;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;

// Retrieve the owner SID for the file
if(GetNamedSecurityInfo(TEXT("myfile.txt"),
                        SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                        OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                        &pSID,
                        NULL, NULL, NULL,
                        &pSD) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    /* error handling */
}

FreeSid(pSID);
LocalFree(pSD);
```

However, when I run the application, it crashes. The debugger reports: `Critical error detected c0000374` and points to the `LocalFree()` line at the end of the snippet above.

Why is this line causing a problem? According to the documentation for the `ppSecurityDescriptor` parameter:

> "A pointer to a variable that receives a pointer to the security descriptor of the object. When you have finished using the pointer, free the returned buffer by calling the LocalFree function."

...which is exactly what I have done.

Comment: I didn't think you had to free the sid (your line prior to the offender). According to the documentation you linked, those pointers refer to data held in the very SD you're already getting back. Short version: remove the `FreeSid` call.

Comment: @WhozCraig: aha! That did the trick. If you post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I only remembered because I was bit by the same thing a few years ago (Different SID, same result). Best of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SID referenced by your `pSID` local var is referring to data already held within the security descriptor referenced by `pSD`. It "owns" that SID, and you own the descriptor reference. You only need to free the latter.

Short version: Remove the `FreeSid(pSID)` call.